# PHP loop through data from external URL

Tags: php

i have this content on an external URL:

```
{"sEcho":null,"iTotalRecords":97,"iTotalDisplayRecords":97,"aaData":[["<a href='#' onClick='return numberPortingShow(\"10621\");'><img border='0' class='tableImage' src='/ControlPanel/Images/Icon/application_view_icons.png' alt='View Porting Details' title='View Porting Details'/></a> <a href='#' onClick='return numberPortingShow(\"10621\");'>0123456789</a>","<a href='/ViewAccount?account_no=20726' target='_blank'>20726</a>","Single Analogue","19/05/2015 14:30","29/05/2015 17:00","Complete”],["<a href='#' onClick='return numberPortingShow(\"10621\");'><img border='0' class='tableImage' src='/ControlPanel/Images/Icon/application_view_icons.png' alt='View Porting Details' title='View Porting Details'/></a> <a href='#' onClick='return numberPortingShow(\"10621\");'>0987654321</a>","<a href='/ViewAccount?account_no=20726' target='_blank'>20726</a>","Single Analogue","19/05/2015 14:30","29/05/2015 17:00","Complete"]]}
```

how can i loop through this data in PHP, while reading it from an external URL

Comment: This looks like json encoded data. Use `json_decode()`. And have fun. Actually the headers you received from that url should have told you so.

Answer (score 1):

Your data looks like JSON string so use `json_decode()` and iterate over it.

```
$data = '{"sEcho":null,"iTotalRecords":97,"iTotalDisplayRecords":97,"aaData":[["<a href='#' onClick='return numberPortingShow(\"10621\");'><img border='0' class='tableImage' src='/ControlPanel/Images/Icon/application_view_icons.png' alt='View Porting Details' title='View Porting Details'/></a> <a href='#' onClick='return numberPortingShow(\"10621\");'>0123456789</a>","<a href='/ViewAccount?account_no=20726' target='_blank'>20726</a>","Single Analogue","19/05/2015 14:30","29/05/2015 17:00","Complete"],["<a href='#' onClick='return numberPortingShow(\"10621\");'><img border='0' class='tableImage' src='/ControlPanel/Images/Icon/application_view_icons.png' alt='View Porting Details' title='View Porting Details'/></a> <a href='#' onClick='return numberPortingShow(\"10621\");'>0987654321</a>","<a href='/ViewAccount?account_no=20726' target='_blank'>20726</a>","Single Analogue","19/05/2015 14:30","29/05/2015 17:00","Complete"]]}';
$dataArray = json_decode($data, true);
foreach ($dataArray as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($key);
    var_dump($value);
}
```

Comment: in the `$data` variable, its commenting out some of it because of the `#` and its having some issues due to the `'` and `"` - whats the best way to help this?

Comment: @charlie I didn't notice, sorry. How you retrieve your data?

Comment: well, its coming from an external URL

Comment: @charlie OK, and how you read it in your code? Are you using cURL or `file_get_contents()`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need php curl, followed by json_decode.

References:

- [get JSON data from url via curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959875/get-json-data-from-url-via-curl)
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php